# Internet shortcuts on home screen

Tags: internet

I've a galaxy s4 running 4.2.2. Using the stock browser not Chrome. Not always but often when I click on Internet shortcuts on my home screen it doesn't take me to the correct site, but rather to the att / yahoo home page. When it does this all the shortcuts on one home screen won't work but go to another home screen and they do work.  Then sometimes later the shortcut will take me to the correct site.  It happens both on wifi and 4g. Sometimes when i toggle wifi/4g they go back to work. Why do the shortcuts not consistently work? By the way if the launcher has any bearing I'm using Holo Launcher HD.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you **edit** that information into your question? It is more visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: "What's up with that?" Pat - I really can't think of an answer. Could you rephrase the question?